# MIPS Boolean Branching Output

Tags: assembly, boolean, mips

I'm not entirely sure how to go about writing this program, and desperately need help:

Instructions:

Write a MIPS program that does the following:

- Places a positive integer n into register `$a0` (e.g., `li $a0,13`)
- If the integer is even, replace the register contents with n/2; otherwise, replace the register contents with 3n + 1. (Don't use the MIPS multiply operation; figure out another way.)
- Print the register contents with a `syscall`

Comment: So you want us to do your homework for you? If you're not entirely sure, then where have you failed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you google for "mips instruction set" and "spim syscall list" you should find all the info you need to solve this.

Comment: I wasn't exactly asking for the full answer, just direction. The second answer given by Michael was all I needed. Much thanks

Comment: So you needed an answer that practically said "google 'mips instruction set' and 'mips syscall list'"?

Comment: honestly, I wasn't sure what to google. There is quite a large sum of programming information on the internet

Answer (score 1):

I know this joint can be pretty rough if it looks like you haven't consulted the Google. But I think you have a valid question on your second bullet - or at least, here are the questions that it would trigger for me:

- How do I figure out if an integer is even?

In a HLL, you would use modulo arithmetic: `if (n % 2 == 0) { // is even }`. But in assembly, you have to do it a different way. Look at the last bit - if it's zero, it's even.

```
andi $t1, $t0, 0x01
beq $t1, $zero, isEven
```

- How do I replace register contents with n/2 without using multiply or divide?

That's one of my favorite things about assembly. Multiplying and dividing by two is as easy as falling off a log. You just shift the bits. In decimal, you multiply by the base (10) by shifting the digits, so 123 * 10 = 1230 and 1230 / 10 = 123. Same in binary (base 2): 0111 * 2 = 1110 and 1110 / 2 = 0111. So all you have to do to (int) divide `$t2` by 2 is:

```
srl $t2, $t2, 1
```

- I assume you can just use add functions for 3n+1. I don't know a "cute" way to do that.